# Multiple projects in one solution to generate one docker container

Tags: git, visual-studio, docker, projects-and-solutions

I have an application which is a visual studio based solution (.sln file) using .NET (could be V4.X or .NET Core). Whole solution is present in one single git repository.

It has multiple projects which could be for example (layers as VS projects) UI layer, business/model layer, data access layer, test projects..

I want to generate one single container for the whole solution.

In visual studio tools for dockers, when adding docker support it is applied to the single project level and therefore the Dockerfile is present in the project. According to my situation I need the Dockerfile at the root of the visual studio solution.

***How to achieve this?***

*I am using VS2015 community edition but please feel free to provide the solution for other versions of the visual studio. It could be useful for anyone.*

Answer (score 0):

Below Docker file you can use for your solution:
Change the version and other directory as you have in your system...!!!

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base`

`WORKDIR /app`

`EXPOSE 80`

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build`

`WORKDIR /src`

`COPY ["project1/project1.csproj", "project1/project1/"]`

`COPY ["project2/project2.csproj", "project2/project2/"]`

`COPY ["project3/project3.csproj", "project3/project3/"]`

`COPY *.sln .`

`COPY *.csproj ./`

`RUN dotnet restore "project1/project1.csproj"`

`RUN dotnet restore "project2/project2.csproj"`

`RUN dotnet restore "project3/project3.csproj"`

`COPY . .`

`WORKDIR "/src/project1/project1"`

`RUN dotnet build "project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build`

`COPY . .`

`WORKDIR "/src/project2/project2"`

`RUN dotnet build "project2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build1`

`COPY . .`

`WORKDIR "/src/project3/project3"`

`RUN dotnet build "project3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build2`

`FROM build AS publish`

`RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish "/src/project1/project1.csproj"`

`RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish1 "/src/project2/project2.csproj"`

`RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish2 "/src/project3/project3.csproj"`

`FROM base AS final`

`WORKDIR /app`

`COPY --from=publish /app/publish .`

`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project1.dll"]`

`COPY --from=publish /app/publish1 .`

`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project2.dll"]`

`COPY --from=publish /app/publish2 .`

`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "project3.dll"]`

Hope it will help someone who is looking for solution like it..!!!